# SSD Reported to Contain 'Bad Sectors'

Tags: ssd

I have a Samsung 840 EV0 250GB SSD that worked fine on several machines before.
I left it on my shelf for a month or two now when I plug it in by USB or SATA it will not show up in disk management, or Windows explorer, but is detected by Windows setup, and by device manager.

So I ran the Western Digital Diagnostics tool. it passed the SMART (basic) test but when I tried to either do a full test or write it with 0's I get an error stating that the drive contains too many bad sectors.

One windows 7 PC does show the drive in disk management, but when I try to make it offline, or initialize it, it says that the drive is write protected.

How do I check for sure if its bad, and how can I get Windows to recognize it.

I need this so that I can replace my noisy HDD with this.

Comment: Possible to  include in an update to  question: the output of the long  smart test ?  also how old is the ssd itself you mentioned it  was in several other machines previously,  was it in any odd or  non standard use case like a RAID array on those other systems?

Comment: @linuxdev2013 the output of the long smart test is  
DLGDIAG For Windows  
Too many bad sectors detected
the SSD is 1 year old (25/12/2014)  
The SSD was in one other PC prior, which used UEFI.  The SSD contained EFI images but those were partially removed using diskpart, as well as any contents on the SSD. after this it still worked fine on any of my computers, windows could see, read and write to it fine. It has not been used in a RAID array.

Answer (score 0):

Your disk is bad.  This is a common way for SSD's to fail.

**Update**

I'd love to know why this answer has been downvoted (and no other answers provided).  Here are some references showing this failure mode as common for SSD's.

- http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2414688/sudden-ssd-failure-years.html
- https://communities.intel.com/thread/30161?start=0&tstart=0
- http://linustechtips.com/main/topic/267028-sudden-ssd-failure-2-years-old-help/
- http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2202985

And Specifically for the Samsung EVO 840 series
- http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1765671/samsung-840-pro-failure.html
 - http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2044429/month-samsung-evo-dead.html
 -

Comment: Davidgo,   have you ever seen a ssd fail just randomly ? I sure have  with  inproper use.

Comment: I've never seen an SSD fail, however I did read up very, very extensively prior to rolling them out across the Org I work for - and what is described above is a very common failure mode.   I'd really like to know why I've been downvoted for my answer)